# I'm going to create a react file.Pls tell me what's the reason this error?

Tags: reactjs

[create a react file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qtt6.png)

I tried several time create react file. already I have downloaded node.js what's this error help me. npx create-app react-domo this is I tried create file but it does't work. anyone can help me slove this struggle.

Answer (score 0):

First remove all react related staff

> npm uninstall -g create-react-app ; npm i -g npm@latest ; npm cache clean -f

then use this command

> npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript